# Apache Commons StringSubstitutor Working in main Method Call but failing when Run As Part of a Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, apache-commons-text

So I am trying to create a method that replaces Placeholders in a block of text read from a file. I have created a method that utilises StringSubstitutor from Apache Commons Text, and when I call my method in the `main` method, it works, yet my Unit Test fails.

The `replacePlaceholders` method:

```java
public StringBuilder replacePlaceholdersInText(Person person) {
        PersonPlaceholders placeholders = new PersonPlaceholders();
        StringBuilder text = READER.readDoc();
        Map<String, String> toReplace = placeholders.getPlaceholders(person);
        StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(toReplace);
        text = new StringBuilder(sub.replace(text));
        LOGGER.info(text);
        return text;
    }
```

PersonPlaceholders Class:

```java
public class PersonPlaceholders implements Placeholders<Person, String, String> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getPlaceholders(Person person) {
        Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        valueMap.put("first_name", person.getFirstName());
        valueMap.put("last_name", person.getLastName());
        valueMap.put("dob", person.getDob().toString());
        return valueMap;
    }
}
```

My Unit Test:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PersonToFileTest {
    @Mock
    WordDocumentReader reader;
    @InjectMocks
    PersonToFile toFile;

@Test
    public void helloJohnDoe() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("John");
        person.setLastName("Doe");
        person.setDob(LocalDate.of(2000, 5, 23));
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}. Your date of birth is ${dob}.");
        StringBuilder expected = new StringBuilder("Hello John Doe. Your date of birth is 2000-05-23.");

        when(reader.readDoc()).thenReturn(text);

        assertEquals(expected, toFile.replacePlaceholdersInText(person));

        verify(reader).readDoc();
    }
}
```

The difference:

```
Expected :Hello John Doe. Your date of birth is 2000-05-23.
Actual   :Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}. Your date of birth is ${dob}.
```

Yet when I run my main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonToFile toFile = new PersonToFile();
        toFile.replacePlaceholdersInText(new Person("John", "Doe", LocalDate.of(2000, 2, 12)));
    }
```

I get this result, (Text is read from a file so that's why format is slightly different):

```
Hi John Doe.
Your date of birth is 2000-02-12.
END OF FILE!
```

I've used Mockito to mock my `WordDocumentReader` Class, and used the debugger to verify that it is being mocked, that the mock is being interacted with.

This seems to be an issue with the `StringSubstitutor.replace()` method not actually being executed in the test, but I am not sure as to why. As I said, the test does everything I expect, until I get to the `.replace` method of the `StringSubstitutor` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I thought creating a `new StringBuilder()` with the result of the `StringSubstitutor.replace()` might not be ideal so I changed the `replacePlaceholdersInText()` to this:

```java
public StringBuilder replacePlaceholdersInText(Person person) {
        PersonPlaceholders placeholders = new PersonPlaceholders();
        StringBuilder text = READER.readDoc();
        Map<String, String> toReplace = placeholders.getPlaceholders(person);
        StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(toReplace);
        text.replace(0, text.length(), sub.replace(text));
        LOGGER.info(text);
        return text;
    }
```

And it worked.

If someone knows of a better way I am all ears, but my Unit test passes, and my `main` method works as expected.

Comment: If you know _why_ this solution works and the code in your question doesn't, it would be useful to explain here. Otherwise, try to write a self-contained executable that others can check and attempt to find the answer.

Comment: @k314159 I have no idea why it worked, at a guess it's to do with not creating a new StringBuilder to overwrite the current string inside it. As for self contained executable, do you mean create a JAR file?

Comment: No, just some code that allows someone to run the code that demonstrates the issue. At the moment, we can't because some classes and/or variables are used whose definitions are missing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Should I add the code as another answer? I am assuming I shouldn't put it in the comments? Or should I edit the post?

Comment: It's best to edit the post.